# Organic reaction rate equations needed

Tags: organic-chemistry, kinetics

Where to find a list of common organic reaction rate laws?? Anybody has this?? I could not find one on internet

Comment: There is a plenty of information you can find by serching for "rate equations"! One such website is: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-chemistry/chapter/the-rate-law-concentration-and-time/

Answer (score 1):

The [Mayr group](https://www.cup.uni-muenchen.de/oc/mayr/) at LMU Munich (Germany) spent a great deal determining rate constants for organic reactions between nucleophiles and electophiles.  They established a public, [searchable database](https://www.cup.lmu.de/oc/mayr/reaktionsdatenbank/) (explained [here](https://www.cup.uni-muenchen.de/oc/mayr/DBintro.html)), and grouped their findings on [posters](https://www.cup.lmu.de/oc/mayr/CDmayrPoster.html) (C-, N-, P-, O-nucleophiles; entries relevant to organometallic chemistry), too.

[image]

([picture source](https://www.cup.uni-muenchen.de/oc/mayr/))

Comment: Even if it wasn't me who asked the question, thank you, great resource!